# 301 Redirect/Rewrite gives loop error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm getting a redirect loop with the following code. How can I fix it?

- first part redirects /links.php to /linked
- second part rewrites /linked to /links.php

`RewriteBase /domain.com`

```
RewriteRule ^links\.php$ linked? [NS,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^linked$ links.php?redirect=no [NS]
```

---

Both ways are working so I'm accepting the first one to post. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the query string that you added in the second rule, so add a RewriteCond in front of the first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=no
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match the original url, instead of the (possibly already) rewritten one using a rewrite-condition:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} links\.php
RewriteRule ^links\.php$ linked? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^linked$ links.php [L]
```